# VBA: Import data between two open worksheets (no path)

Tags: vba, excel

I open two Workbooks that are part of the a 3D CAD file and have not real path.

Anyway, after I open them manually I want VBA to move, say, A1 from Workbook B To Workbook A.

In order for VBA to know the name of the source, I say the name of Workbook B is stored in B1 of Workbook A

I know how to move data if I have a path but since there is "none", how do I do that? Thank you!

Comment: (a) The "path" of the workbook would not normally be used when referencing open workbooks (e.g. code might be `Workbooks("xyz.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")` but wouldn't be `Workbooks("C:\abc\def\xyz.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")`)  (b) If you have something in the workbooks identifying which is workbook A and which is workbook B, you should be able to loop through all open workbooks and Set a variable of type Workbook to the workbook when you find the one matching the appropriate criteria, and then use that variable to refer to the workbook from then on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going back and forth i found out that this works too:

```
Private Sub import_Click()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set wb2 = ActiveWorkbook
Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("sheet1")

Set wb1 = Workbooks(ActiveSheet.Range("n2").Value & ".xls")
Set ws1 = wb1.Sheets("input")


ws2.Range("a1") = ws1.Range("f90").Value
End Sub
```

Thank you for the good ideas

Answer (score 1):

Hope this help.

```
Dim FrmWorkbook As Workbook
Dim iCount As Integer

'Capture the source workbook
For i = 1 To ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks.Count
    'change the name of your source Workbook below
    If ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks(i).Name = "Book1.xlsx" Then
        Set FrmWorkbook = ThisWorkbook.Application.Workbooks(i)
        Exit For
    End If
Next

'option 1: row by row or column by colum.  (Column C)
Dim lRow As Long

For lRow = 1 To 100
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C" & lRow).Value = FrmWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("C" & lRow).Value
Next

'option 2: copy the entire sheet (assuming Sheet1)
With FrmWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    .Activate
    .Select
    .Copy before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
End With

Set FrmWorkbook = Nothing

MsgBox "DONE"
```

Comment: Oh, run that from a module in your current workbook (destination workbook).